# What is the best way to store a sensitive key on an android app?

Tags: android, security, storage, keystore

I have to store a sensitive passphrase in my android app. That passphrase can be regenerated by a user if needed.
My first idea was to store it in a keystore file protected by a password.
But this password, where should I store it?
I don't care if it's the same for all my android applications but I don't want the users to read it.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is not to do this.  Why are your storing a password?  You should almost never need to do this.

If you are doing it to authenticate with your server-  don't.  Instead, use a token based system with a token generated by your server and refreshed occassionally.

If you're doing it to authenticate with the client-  I'd use the built in secureity on Android.

In general if you MUST store a password, don't save it as is.  Hash it, salt it, and store that instead.  That way if your app is compromised, they can't get the password itself, which could be reused.

Once all that is done if you have a key that needs to be secured, you can look into Android's keystore system:  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore

Comment: My need is to encrypt and decrypt all communications between our Android tablet and a physical device provided by our partner. We therefore share a secret key between us and must use it to secure all requests. Also, the app installed on our tablet should work without an internet connection, so we can't store it anywhere other than on the tablet.

Comment: I'd recommend just using SSL for the encryption and not rolling your own.  You're not going to get it right.  That's not an insult, the vast majority of people in the field wouldn't get it right either.  Then you don't nee to worry about secret keys, you can just encrypt with the public ones.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: I totally agree with you except that this is not our choice but the one of our partner, their device requires an SSL connection AND an encryption with a shared key

Comment: "Also, the app installed on our tablet should work without an internet connection, so we can't store it anywhere other than on the tablet." So how the app and the device provider by the partner is communicating with each other? Bluetooth or some other protocol? You said that you need shared key to communicate between app and the device and then that key cannot be stored anywhere else then tablet as the app should work offline. But if it is offline why it need the key in the first place as it cannot communicate with the device(via SSL) either?

Answer (score 0):

When storing any sensitive values in an Android binary file (or any binary file for that matter) think of it as simply making it harder to get to. If someone is determined to get the key or password or passphrase, then they will get it. You are just making it harder for someone to get it.

The best you could do is have some sort of server-side verification for what you are trying to do. This will be the most secure way for you and you can also add an extra layer of protection by making it so that only your app can get that passphrase.
If you do not have a server, then the best you can do is compile the passphrase and other information in a C++ lib file and fetch it from Kotlin or Java.

If though, that passphrase can be changed by a user, why not let the users set it up from the get go and not store it anywhere? You can use Firebase (which is basically free) to have some sort of authentication and also persist user set passwords across devices and app installs.